# Randomly add and deduct a number for my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, numbers

I'm new to javascript/jquery and I can't seem to find any answers for a script that randomly changes the number I have on my website...

---

So this is what I'm looking for:
I've a number (lets say 200) and I want this number to increase and decrease randomly between 100 and 300 every second.

### So it needs change the number it displays like this: 200 -> 230 -> 166-> 281 -> 105-> 195 and so on...

Obviously the numbers are just an example.
Many thanks in advance if someone is able to help me out!

Comment: Do you hav e some code documenting your attempt at a solution?

Comment: Run a random addition/subtraction function inside a `setInterval` loop

Comment: I don't think you've progressed to the point where you should be asking a Stack Overflow question - consider researching: a) How to execute a function every time interval, b) How to generate a random number, c) How to modify the text/innerHTML of an element using JavaScript (if you need to display this in the DOM). Attempt to solve the problem yourself, and only bring it here if you run into issues with your solution.

Comment: I don't think adding / reducing provides anything here, it looks like you just want a number in the [100, 300] range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $('#i').val(randomIntFromInterval(100,300) );
}, 1000);

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsbosck1/

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for helping me out!
The javascript works exactly as I hoped it would, just have 1 questions...

Is it possible to have this shown without the input field or at least make it look like it's not in an input field, but just plain text?

On the page I'm creating I have: 
"people watching this video right now: 200" 
and the 200 is obviously the number that needs to run up and down...

Comment: @dwayneE I made an update for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qsbosck1/1/

Comment: Works like a charm! You are the best!
Thanks for helping me out Thomas and thanks for the js.fiddle links!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var randomNumber = function( min, max ) {
    return min + Math.round( Math.random() * ( max - min ) );
};

var iterate = function() {
    var number = randomNumber( 100, 300 );
    //do something with number
};

setInterval( iterate, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is..

```
var myNumber = 200;
var count = 0;

function nextTick() {
    var plusOrMinus = (count++) % 2 ? -1 : 1;
    var randomNumber = Math.round( (Math.random() * 200 + 100));
    myNumber += (randomNumber * plusOrMinus);
    return myNumber;
}

console.log( myNumber );
setInterval( function() {
    console.log( nextTick() );
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap your number with a `span` tag

`<span id="number">200</number>` **oops, corrected**: `<span id="number">200</span>`

then, change your number with

```
function changeNumber() {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = 
      Math.floor(100 + Math.random()*200); 
}
```

and run this function every second with

```
window.setInterval(changeNumber,1000);
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aqw339r0/15/

Comment: not to be a jerk, but you close your span with a number tag. That can't be right